# SVG color gets black when using dom-to-image plugin

Tags: javascript, html, image, reactjs, svg

I am in a situation where I need to export the following SVG as a pdf so I am using the dom-to-image plugin listed in NPM plugin directory.
So the problem is when I try to export the following SVG as an image the color of the SVG gets black.

I tried some options listed in the dom-to-image options but those are for the parent node the SVG I am trying to export is in its child node.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="foo"><svg class="cone" viewBox="-25 0 1175 1419" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="Canvas" transform="translate(19600 8843)">
<g id="Group 5">
<g id="Group 6">
<g id="Group 5">
<g id="Vector 3.4">
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path10_fill" transform="translate(-19604.5 -7783)" fill="#3596ff">
</use>
</g>
</g>
</g>
</g>
</g>
<defs>
<path id="path10_fill" d="M 0 208L 85 0C 230.833 82 623.9 196.8 1047.5 0L 1138 208C 842 441.5 137 369.5 0 208Z">
</path>
</defs>
</svg>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const render = node =>
  domtoimage.toPng(node)
  .then(dataUrl => {
  console.log(performance.now()-pf)
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = dataUrl;
    $('body').append(img);
  })
  .catch(error =>
    console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error)
  );

const foo = document.getElementById('foo');

var pf=performance.now();
render(foo);
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/harish_soni/zejutgL4/)

**NOTE**: Please scroll down in the output part to see the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin probably doesn't recognize the `<use>` tag. You can just change the `fill="#3596ff"` to the `<svg>` tag or the `<path>` tag if you're going to have more than one path.